# MySQl Configuration Error After reinstall it

Tags: mysql

When I reinstall MySQL database after uninstall it, I got this error when configuration:

[image] Error 1045

Now, My new directory is here:

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
```

and my old directory was this:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
```

I delete whole MySQl folder on drive c , But it has error when want to config!
 How can i fix this problem?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: I think that you should delete mysql folder in your installed drive, in program data folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this method as well:

1. Menu>Start>Run>CMD
   `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld.exe" --skip-grant-tables`
2. Let's this window open and open a new one
   `Menu>Start>Run>CMD
   "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe" -u root`
3. You're now connect to MySQL, you have to modified the root account in the date of MySQL

   `mysql> use mysql;`

   `mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('motdepasse') WHERE user="root";`

   `mysql> flush privileges;`

   `mysql> exit;`
4. Restart with MySQL Command Line Client

That's it

Comment: I try it, But say that The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Path should be your own installation path

Comment: Should i write --skip-grant-tables in the end of line and press enter?

Comment: When i write second command in new command line window, this message displayed:

Comment: Error 1045 (28000): access denied for user 'ODBC' @ 'localhost' (using password: No)

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the data directory and then retry to install it, it should be in:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data

As mentioned on the last paragraph of your screenshot:

*If you are re-installing after you just uninstalled the MySQL server please note that the data directory was not removed automatically. Therefore the old password from your last installation is still needed to connect to the server. In this case please select skip now and re-run the Configuration Window from the start menu.*

Comment: I use windows 7, Where is this directory?

Comment: Try this:

Check the my.ini file in the folder where MYSQL is/was installed. Normally the folder is at C:\Program Files\MySQL\yourVersionOfMysql. Once there open the my.ini file and you will see a line like this: datadir=”C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/” <- the url might change...

Comment: Or try to find it at:
C:\Users\youruser\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```
1. "Add or Remove Programs
2. Deleted c:\mysql
3. Rebooted the PC
4. Reinstalled MySQL
```

Comment: Delete mysql folder in program data folder too.